# How to change Ubuntu title bar text

Tags: themes, customization

I would like some help. I need to change the "Ubuntu Desktop" text in the top panel in Ubuntu 14.01 bar to say "Titan OS". How would I achieve that? I am using the Flatty theme, and would like to keep that in the process. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Screenshot of what you mean - upload to http://imgur.com? Any reason why?

Comment: which ubuntu version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Thank you that worked.

What I had to do, was open up Unity.mo, and change the "Ubuntu Desktop^Ubuntu  Desktop" at the end; to "Ubuntu Desktop^Titan OS".

For the help of other looking to do the same. Here is the commands that finally did it.

```
cd /
cd /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
sudo nano unity.mo
```

Scroll to the end, and change "Ubuntu Desktop^Ubuntu Desktop" to "Ubuntu Desktop^Titan OS"

Answer (score 1):

I remember from once trying the [MacUbuntu](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html) theme pack that it included a step to change the name at the top left corner of the Unity screen - these instructions are for 14.04:

> Enter following commands to change 'Ubuntu Desktop' text on the panel:
>
> ```
> Terminal Commands:
> cd && wget -O Mac.po http://drive.noobslab.com/data/Mac-14.04/change-name-on-panel/mac.po
> cd /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES; sudo msgfmt -o unity.mo ~/Mac.po;rm ~/Mac.po;cd
> ```
>
> Revert back to 'Ubuntu Desktop' text, enter following commands in the
>   Terminal:
>
> ```
> Terminal Commands:
> cd && wget -O Ubuntu.po http://drive.noobslab.com/data/Mac-14.04/change-name-on-panel/ubuntu.po
> cd /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES; sudo msgfmt -o unity.mo ~/Ubuntu.po;rm ~/Ubuntu.po;cd
> ```

This is the contents of the `~/Mac.po` file:

```
msgid "Ubuntu Desktop"
msgstr "Mac OS X"
```

and here is the contents of the `~/Ubuntu.po` file:

```
msgid "Mac OS X"
msgstr "Ubuntu Desktop"
```

So *at a guess (not tested - not using Unity)* you can do this to change it to 'Titan OS':

```
echo -e 'msgid "Ubuntu Desktop"\nmsgstr "Titan OS" > ~/Titan.po
cd /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
sudo msgfmt -o unity.mo ~/Titan.po
```

This should change it back

```
echo -e 'msgid "Titan OS"\nmsgstr "Ubuntu Desktop"' > Ubuntu2.po
cd /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
sudo msgfmt -o unity.mo ~/Ubuntu2.po
```